# F# Chaining functions that return tuple

Tags: f#

I am new to F# and am trying to chain functions to make a Higher Order Function.

A simplified example is

`init` returns a tuple

`validate` accepts a tuple and returns `bool`

```ml
    let init : string * string =
        ("1", "2")

    let validate ((a: string), (b: string)) : bool =
        a.Equals(b)

    let test = init >> validate
```

**ERROR**

`This expression was expected to have type 'a -> 'b'     but here has type 'string * string'`

Comment: Init is not a function, but just a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only compose functions using the >> combinator. Your first assignment is not a function - it is a binding to a value - your tuple.
You can convert it to a function just by adding empty parameter list () (unit) parameter like this:

```ml
let init() : string * string =
    ("1", "2")

let validate ((a: string), (b: string)) : bool =
    a.Equals(b)

let test = init >> validate

let res = test()
```

Answer (score 5):

As the answer for Piotr explains, you are getting an error because you have a value and a function. To compose those, you can turn `init` into a function, but you do not really need to use composition in this case.

If you want to pass a value as an argument to a function, it is typically much simpler to just pass it as an argument:

```
let res = validate init
```

Alternatively, if you have a number of functions you want to apply to your input in a sequence, you can do this using the piping operator:

```
let res = init |> validate
```

Function composition using `>>` is a nice functional trick, but I think it is actually much less common in standard F# code than most people think. I use `|>` all the time, but `>>` only rarely.